# bash: remove all files except last version in file name

Tags: python, bash, sh

I have 10K+ files like below. File system date(export time) is one for all files.

```
YYY101R1.corp.company.org-RUNNINGCONFIG-2015-07-10-23-10-15.config
YYY101R1.corp.company.org-RUNNINGCONFIG-2015-07-11-22-11-10.config
YYY101R1.corp.company.org-RUNNINGCONFIG-2015-10-01-10-05-08.config

LLL101S1.corp.company.org-RUNNINGCONFIG-2015-08-10-23-10-15.config
LLL101S1.corp.company.org-RUNNINGCONFIG-2015-09-11-20-11-10.config
LLL101S1.corp.company.org-RUNNINGCONFIG-2015-10-02-19-05-07.config
```

How can I delete all files except last version(last date) of file from file name and rename it to

```
YYY101R1.corp.company.org.config  
LLL101S1.corp.company.org.config
```

Comment: lets start with the code you have for generating the list of files...

Answer (score 0):

The UNIX shell command

```
ls -t YYY101R1.corp.company.org*
```

will list files in order of age, newest first.  Grab the first line as "latest" and make a symbolic ("soft") link to it:

```
ln -s $latest YYY101R1.corp.company.org.config
```

Repeat for each file group.

Comment: I have correct time in file name only, so sort by timestamps does not work.

Comment: That makes it a tiny amount easier: your naming sorts the files in order.  Use 'ls -r' to put the newest file first -- by name, instead of by time stamp.

Answer (score 0):

I got something similar, first get list of all files sorted ascending by modification time, then get number of them, display all minus last 2 of them and pass that to list to command removing file.

`ls -tr | wc -l`

`ls -tr | head -number_of_files_minus_2 | xargs rm`

Was it helpful?

Comment: I have correct file date and time in file name only. System file times is same for all files (export date and time).

Comment: So maybe for the first command, just alphabetical sorting `ls | sort -t- -k3` This will sort files by date in filenames.

Comment: is there way to get numbers of  file groups for head - ?

Comment: Could you be more specific? What groups? Head command is for printing out first part of file(s) - by default first 10 lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
FLast=`ls -tr 'YYY101R1.corp.company.org*' | tail -n 1`

mv ${FLast} YYY101R1.corp.company.org.config
rm -f YYY101R1.corp.company.org-RUNNINGCONFIG-*
```